# Why does olive oil make 90 degree grids on a nonstick pan?

Tags: organic-chemistry, food-chemistry, fats

[image: olive oil making grids in a nonstick pan when swirled]

Whenever I add olive oil to my cold nonstick pan and try to swirl it, it ends up making these 90-degree grids. Is this something to do with the oil, the pan, or the interaction between the two? I find the regular spacing between lines rather interesting.

Comment: It doesn't do on my pan …

Comment: Are you swirling it in an orbital motion, or first shaking it in the x direction, and then shaking it in the y direction?

Comment: Must be the pan... perhaps parts of the PTFE coating was not fully applied, and oil sticks there.

Comment: I have never seen this on any of my nonstick pans before. What happens if you try it with rubbing alcohol?